# RemoteViews to update own View item

Tags: android, widget, remoteview

In my Widget app i update the onscreen layout using a remote view, since i would also like to create a preview of that result under main configuration activity i've tried to use Remote Views also there to save me from rewriting some code, what i want to do is something like:

```
    // "vg" is an inflated R.layout.widget viewgroup
    RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, "foo");
    rv.apply(context, vg);
```

However the "apply" function doesn't seem to update anything on ViewGroup, no error is returned.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe you can do that: it is a nice idea, but in the absence of a fully functional RemoteView host you are out of luck there.

What you want to do is just inflate R.layout.widget into a regular ViewGroup in your Activity and fill it in.

Comment: Yep, that's what im doing now, but it is a waste of code lines and it's also error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help someone

```
FrameLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.container);
View view = RemoteViews.apply(getActivity(), parent);
parent.addView(view);
```

Original answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21917352/9400836