# Converting RemoteView into a View

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to render a RemoteViews instance onto a Canvas, like I do with a regular View. I use

> RemoteViews.apply(context, null)

and it returns a FrameLayout with all the views nested and properly measured (location and size is correct,) but after using .draw on the returned view, it renders all elements with no values -- TextViews are empty, AnalogClock is reset at 00:00 and so on.

Any ideas? I'm lost :(

Comment: Try to step into system libraries in debugger.

Comment: Please post your xml. At what point are you setting the values for the TextViews, AnalogClock, etc.?

Comment: @KarimVarela simple AnalogClock, no values in xml aside the layout_width and layout_height. When rendering on device, it shows the correct time, in View returned by apply(), it shows 00:00 always.

Comment: You must have set values using `setTextViewText()` or other setter-methods somewhere, right? Are you sure you set appropriate values on the right `RemoteViews` instance before calling `apply()`?

Comment: can you post your code here? What I feel is... it might be possible that you might be calling RemoteViews.apply(context, null) before setting up the values in textviews but calling after initializing  thats why its not getting Force close but coming with empty values.
So set your values to the textview and clock and then call your method RemoteViews.apply(context, null); Also what is second parameter in your method that you are passing as null.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if the question is still actual. Nevertheless here is my experience with RemoveViews. It appears you cannot just call `draw()` on the returned view. You have to add this view to a parent container to make it a part of global view hierarchy. For instance, you have an `Activity` with a single `FrameLayout` in it. Your code will look like this.

```
FrameLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.container);
View view = RemoteViews.apply(getActivity(), parent);
parent.addView(view);
```

Now you should be able to see tests. If you set listeners, they will work properly too.