# How to get all notification of all application have custom notification running

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar, remoteview

I'm a beginner. I have a problem about custom notification.
I want to read all information of normal notification and custom notification use RemoteView.
Example I want get all information about notification music(art cover, song, next, pause, back action)
I search very very much, but can't find the document I need.
If you know, please tell me.
Thank so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html). From the docs:

> A service that receives calls from the system when new notifications are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.

If you're specifically looking for ways to read Metadata and the music app is using a [`MediaSessionCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html), you can use [`MediaControllerCompat.getMetadata()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html#getMetadata()) to read the data off of the notification.

To display the actual content of the notification in your app, what you can do is get one of the many `RemoteView`s from the `Notification` object you received, then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444118/converting-remoteview-into-a-view) answer to display your notification.

Comment: i'm using it. but i can't get all information.
I want to get all information and show custom notification of application runing @@
Do you get the message? T__T
Show same as status bar of system. ^^

Comment: I'm not sure if you can actually get what you want, especially with custom RemoteViews, due to unknown view IDs but you can get the ticker text from a notification which might help. Also did you see my edit about music apps?

Comment: When a application have custom notification running in my phone, status bar will show custom notification of app. (my english not well, so sorry @@ )
I want to show like it. @@ get infor and SHOW custom notification.
Thank so much! ^_^

Comment: So you want to show the notification in your own app?

Comment: yes Sir.
I want to custom status bar of system. =.=
do you understand? @_@

Comment: You can just accept the answer, you don't have to upvote

Comment: I did it. Thank for your help. Thank so much ^^

Comment: No problem! Anytime.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Can i ask you about this?

Comment: Sure thing. It's probably best to make a new question and link it here though.

Comment: I did it. ^^
Very happy : ))
Thank Andrew ^_^